What does "garb" mean in this passage?
In Einstein, History, and Other Passions: The Rebellion Against Science at the End of the Twentieth Century Gerald James Holton writes:

Here Spengler introduces his most startling idea, one that has become familiar in new garb also. He warns that it is characteristic of the winter phase of civilization that precisely when high science is most fruitful within its own sphere, the seeds of its undoing begin to sprout. (source)

The noun "garb" in my understanding means clothing or garment. Google shows another definition but in the realm of heraldry which doesn't seem relevant to the context at hand either. What does it mean here?
I think the current answer does a good job explaining the meaning of the phrase "in (a) new garb" but doesn't really explain it in the context given. It'd make sense to me if it were "Spengler re-introduced an idea in new garb" in the book but it isn't. Rather Holton seems to suggest here that Spengler introduces an idea he hasn't talked about before. So what does Holton mean here?

I edited the question seeking clarification and then I got downvoted. Wowsers

I don't know why the question was downvoted, but the reason may be unrelated with the content of the edit. The edit just sent the question back to the top of the active questions, where someone who didn't like it downvoted it ... That's my guess.

That said, part of what you added "I think the current answer ..." is more appropriate as a comment than as part of the question.

"Garb" here means "clothing" in a figurative sense, i.e. the third meaning given by Wiktionary:


(figurative) A guise, external appearance.


The phrase "in (a) new garb" when discussing old ideas, concept or arguments is rather common. Below are a few other examples:

Dick and His Cat: An Old Tale in a New Garb by Mary Ellis (i.e. an old story retold in a new way);
An old play in a new garb : (Hamlet, prince of Denmark) by George Edward Rice (an adaptation of Shakespeare's Hamlet);
Values Education in New Zealand: Old Ideas in New Garb (title of a paper in the journal Citizenship, Social and Economics Education, 2000);
Why the poor do not expropriate the rich: an old argument in new garb (title of a paper in Journal of Public Economics, 1998);
Sri Lanka: Old ghosts in new garb: Sri Lanka’s return to fear (article by Amnesty International; the ghosts aren't literal, either).

The text cited in the question takes a different spin on this: Spengler's idea is now old and more recent authors have reused it "in new garb".

That makes sense in itself but doesn't really explain the text at issue in context. All the examples you cite here are in a set, recognizable pattern: old ideas/tales/stories reinterpreted/retold/rebranded/refurbished. It'd make sense to me if it were "Spengler re-introduced an idea in new garb" in the book but it isn't. (personally I'd've said "an old idea in new clothes" which is much more common) Rather Holton seems to suggest here that Spengler introduces an idea he hasn't talked about before.

@desmo I'm not claiming that Spengler was introducing an old idea "in new garb". In the text you cite, Spengler's idea is now an old one that others have reused, i.e. presented "in new garb". I'll edit my answer to clarify this.
